# Ajax on Ror, Networkerror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm working in a simple increment fonction who is not working. In my console I have this error "NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - ..../test/increment_nbr" and I'm not able to fix it.

Html:

```
<button id="incr">AJAX2</button>
<script>
$("#incr").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
     url: "/test/increment_nbr",
     dataType: "json",
     type: "POST",
     success: function(data) {
     }
     });
   })
</script>
```

My controller:

```
respond_to :html, :json
def increment_nbr
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.increment! :nbr_set
    render json: { nbr: @user.nbr_set }.to_json
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :test do
    member do
       put :increment_nbr
       post :increment_nbr
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your routing is incorrect - you've defined your two `increment_nbr` routes as member routes, meaning they operate on an instance of your parent `test` route and would generate URLs like `/test/2/increment_nbr`.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions for more information